# why $(document).html() cannot get whole html string?Is there other methods to get this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the

```
$(document).html()
```

return empty rather than the whole html string.How to get it?

Comment: note that it will return the browser's interpretation of the original string rather than the original html of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do it with Javascript outerHTML propery, no jquery code required.

Simply use : `document.documentElement.outerHTML`

This will give you entire HTML along with HTML tag and its associated attributes.

If you want it using jQuery use:-

```
$('html')[0].outerHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

Its fairly easy, just use

```
$('html').html()
```

Answer (score 1):

i didnt test this one..why not try

```
    $('html').html();
```

Comment: it doesn't include doctype and <html>,it is close,but not the one.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the

```
$(document).text()
```

***Demo*** : Open chrome's inspect element( Developer's Tools) and type the following..You'll see the result :)

Comment: it doesn't include any html tags,eg head,body, input.